# Check a String is Palindrome or not. C++

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

What is wrong in this?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string str)
{
  char temp[1000];
  int len=str.length();
  int i=0;
  while(len)
  {
    len--;
    temp[i++]=str[len];
  }
  temp[i]='\0';
  if (strcmp(str,temp)==0)
     return true;
  else
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong? Please provide enough details so that the next person with the same problem can find this question and benefit from it. *You should also provide enough detail to distinguish your question from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+string+palindrome).*

Comment: look ok - you run and you saw this not give right result ?

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` is not a standard C++ header. Don't use it. Ever.

Comment: Tip: you don't need to copy the string. Think how you'd do it if the text was written on a piece of paper.

Comment: we sometimes need to focus on the question .. he ask what he did wrong and not how to right it better :)

Comment: Just about everything. `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` should never be used, `using namespace std;` should never be used, `temp` is totally unneeded, 1000 is a meaningless arbitrary value, `strcmp` is not applicable to `std::string`. All of this can be done in one line of idiomatic C++.

Comment: You could use `std::reverse` to reverse a `std::string` and then compare the original and reversed version for equality. Less than a handful of code lines to do (and there are other equally simple options). This is way too complex compared to what's needed with modern idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you do it:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>

bool isPalindrome(std::string_view const str) {
    return std::equal(str.begin(), str.begin() + str.size() / 2, str.rbegin());
}
```

Highlights:

[std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)
[std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)
[std::string_view::rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/rbegin)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is far more complex than it should be.

```
bool isPalindrome(const string& str) {
    int i = 0, j = str.size() - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (str[i] != str[j]) return false;
        i++, --j;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Another implementation:

```
bool isPalindrome(const string& str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; i++)
        if (str[i] != str[str.size() - i - 1])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

`strcmp()` function that you are using, accepts only c-string as arguments, but you are passing C++ string. Also it won't work if `string str` length is more than 1000.

Comment: The first one will do bad things when `str` is empty.

Comment: What bad things? @PeteBecker

Comment: @DimitrijeCiric Well, try it with an empty string and you'll see

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I tried, everything is correct. Returns 1, that is what it should return.

Comment: I'm still not sure what's supposed to go wrong in the empty `str` case. `str.size() - 1` is a huge positive unsigned number, but then it gets assigned to an `int` and ends up being `-1`, so the `while` loop is never entered and `true` is immediately returned. What's the catastrophe?

Comment: @DimitrijeCiric `str.size() - 1` becomes a huge positive number, which overflows the `j`, which is, formally, undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanPierson it's undefined behavior...

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili It's [implementation-defined until C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) and the expected value according to modular arithmetic since then. Not UB.

Comment: @NathanPierson sure, still not good. And can be avoided with a cast to ptrdiff_t, or just using the second version.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili No need of casting, we can just use `size_t` (`for (size_t i{}, j{str.size()}; i < j--; ++i) { if (str[i] != str[j]) return false; }`), iterators or `std::ssize()`.

Comment: @Bob__ well, I don't get your point. Yes, there are other ways of doing this, one is even in this answer.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili The snippet in this answer shows a conversion from the type returned by `std::string::size` to `int`. I suggested *not* to perform a conversion (as you did in your answer, sticking to iterators).

Comment: Could someone please make me understand this line "const string& str" ?

Comment: `const string& str`, means that `str` will not be changed in that function and `&` means that it's passed by reference, so `string` is not copied. If you have `string& str` it will pass string by reference and because it's not const if you change `str` in that function it will be changed outside that function. It's just a summary of that, there is a far bigger story about that. @SKD